# Center UITextView text vertically

Tags: ios, uitextview

I know this question has been asked in the past, but the answers do not work in iOS 9.2. I'm trying to center the text in my UITextView vertically, but when I do:

```
textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

and

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let textView = object as! UITextView
    var topCorrect = (textView.bounds.size.height - textView.contentSize.height * textView.zoomScale) / 2
    topCorrect = topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect;
    textView.contentInset.top = topCorrect
}
```

nothing happens in the text view. Any thoughts? This used to be the answer.

Comment: did you take UITesxtView in storyboard or nib and take IBOutlet in code ?

Comment: Does it need to be a UITextView? If you can use a UILabel instead labels center their content vertically by default, textViews do not